# Deleting Cookies In Other Subdomains

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I was wondering if it's possible to delete a cookie in PHP, meaning re-setting it's time to a time in the past, for a specific subdomain from another subdomain.

For example:

say I am executing the following code on one.myserver.com, which is meant to delete a cookie on two.myserver.com

```
setcookie("ACOOKIE", 0, time() - 3600, "/", "two.myserver.com");
```

Currently doing it this way is not working for me. Is there any way I could get something like this to work?

Comment: Consider what a security nightmare it would be if the $_SESSION variable cookie were cross-site accessible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you can only do that from the other subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

You dont even know that they exist because they will only be sent(by the client browser) while accessing the domain where they were originally meant for.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Cookies can only be set and unset from the same fully qualified domain.